# Como puedo Imprimir directamente(sin cuadro de dialogo) en un sitio web con angularJS a una impresora bluetooh Zebra !MZ320

Tags: javascript, html, c#, angularjs

El asunto es que estoy creando un sitio web y necesito imprimir un ticket (como los quedan en el banco para esperar) y para ello necesito que sea directo del boton imprimir de mi app web a imprimir a la impresora. He buscado por todo lado y no encuentro nada. Estoy programando en AngularJS, ademas necesito que sirva en dispositivos móviles. Un saludo Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no podrás sin sacar un cuadro de diálogo por un tema de seguridad, (imaginate que cada vez que entraras en una pagina web te imprimiera guarradas la impresora, jeje). De todas maneras mirate esto que he encontrado en el site en inglés, lo imprime en formato string:

Este programador ha usado este proyecto http://nwjs.io/ y este  paquete de js 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977475/node-js-use-printer-hardware

> I did an application like that.. I did it using http://nwjs.io/  and
>   the module in the comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer, here
>   is a working code with this module printing raw in the default printer
>   a file:

```
var printer = require('printer');
var fs = require('fs');

var info = fs.readFileSync('ticket.txt').toString();

function sendPrint() {
  printer.printDirect({
    data: info,
    type: 'RAW',
    success: function (jobID) {
      console.log("ID: " + jobID);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log('printer module error: '+err);
      throw err;
    }
  });
}

sendPrint();
```

Comment: dudo mucho que eso funcione. Está leyendo un fichero de texto del ordenador cliente. Si esto se lanza desde un navegador, me temo no habrá nada que hacer. Y si se lanza desde un interprete node, entonces no hay problema para imprimir directamente

Answer (score 0):

Es totalmente alcanzable, pero ten en cuenta algunas cosas, como:

1.- No importa si la impresora es bluetooth, wifi o cable, la impresora debe de estar conectada a tu dispositivo.
2.- No conozco AngularJs, pero se que en el frontend solo funciona Javascript así que sin importar el framework o libreria `window.print()` deberia de funcionar.
3.- El diseño para impresión debe de ser distinto al diseño de tu pagina, esto se logra con css.

El siguiente ejemplo utilizo Jquery, pero lo importante es el `window.print()` y los css para impresion:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send-print").click(function(){
    window.print();
  })
})
```

```css
@media print{
.no-imprime{
display:none;
}
#send-print{
display:none;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="imprime">
Hola esto debe de imprimierse
</div>
<div class="no-imprime">
Hola esto no debe de imprimierse
</div>
<button id="send-print">imprimir</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Exiten muchas otras maneras de hacerlo, aqui te comparto un link donde lo hacen diferente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255438/8705724

Al final realiza algunas configuraciones: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/285475/48306