# ¿Cómo imprimir desde JavaScript sin confirmacion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Cómo puedo hacer para imprimir un objeto del `DOM` sin que aparezca el cuadro de dialogo de confirmación por parte del cliente?

Escribí este código y funciona:

```
function Imprimir(){
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h3>' + 'Impresion de documento' + '</h3>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('divContenido').innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
```

Pero siempre aparece este cuadro de dialogo, el cual es el que deseo evitar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso es propio del navegador, y no puedes controlar esos eventos del navegador

Comment: La respuesta sencilla: *no es posible*, Javascript no está pensado para realizar dicha tarea. Para poder imprimir se necesita la información del tipo de impresora y del Sistema Operativo. Dicha información sólo la maneja el Navegador y no está accesible para Javascript. Saludos

Answer (score 7):

Tengo entendido que no se puede hacer por cuestiones de seguridad, JavaScript no le permiten tener acceso directo a la impresión por lo que es competencia del navegador.
La única solución que he conseguido para impresión silenciosa es configurar el navegador para que salte el dialogo de impresión y ejecute el comando solicitado sin pedirle autorización al usuario. (Esta practica es util para puntos de venta que necesitan imprimir directamente sin necesidad de confirmacion del usuario).

**PARA CHROME:**

1) Abre el navegador e imprime una página de prueba para configurar los parámetros de la impresora

2) cerrar todo el chrome

2) Crea un nuevo acceso directo del google Chrome

3) Hacer click con el botón derecho del mouse para ver el menú contextual del acceso directo creado para “google Chrome” y seleccionar propiedades.

4) en el campo de la ruta target: colocar el final el parámetro: --kiosk-printing

5) aplicar cambios y OK

6) Ejecutar el nuevo acceso directo de Chrome

7) Probar el codigo de impresión nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PARA FIREFOX:**

1) Abre el navegador e imprime una página de prueba para configurar los parámetros de la impresora

2) tipear en el campo de la ruta la dirección:  about:config

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) dar en aceptar a la advertencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4) buscar la variable  "print.always_print_silent" en caso de no existir hacer click con el botón izquierdo NEW ->  Boolean y poner esta  en el campo y pulsar OK (como valor colocaremos TRUE = que corresponderá a imprimir directamente sin ventana de dialogo, cuando queramos tener la ventana de impresión colocamos la variable en FALSE)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5) cerramos y volvemos abrir el Firefox

6) Probar el codigo de impresión nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LO HE PROBADO Y FUNCIONA!!!

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Al menos en Firefox que fue donde lo probé.